# how does the linked list goes to the second node

Tags: python

so I am learning linked lists in python, but I didn't understand how does the linked list goes to the second node as it assigns the next node as the root node, please explain it to me, thanks.
the code

```
class Node
    def __init__(self,d,n=None,p=None):
        self.data=d
        self.next_node=n
        self.previous_node=p
    def __str__(self):
        return ('(' + str(self.data) + ')')

class linked_list:
    def __init__(self,r=None):
        self.root=r
        self.size=0
    def add(self,d):
        new_node=Node(d,self.root)#here i didn't understand how we assign the next node
        self.root=new_node
        self.size +=1
        
    def find(self,d):
        this_node=self.root
        while this_node is not None:
            if this_node.data==d:
                print(this_node.next_node)
                return this_node.data
            else:
                this_node = this_node.next_node
        return None
    def remove(self,d):
        this_node=self.root
        previouse_node=None
        while this_node is not None:
            if this_node.data==d:
                if previouse_node is not None:
                    previouse_node.next_node=this_node.next_node
                else:
                    self.root=this_node.next_node
                    self.size -=1
            else:
                previouse_node=this_node
                this_node=this_node.next_node
        return False
    def print_list(self):
        this_node = self.root
        while this_node is not None:
            print(this_node, end='->')
            this_node = this_node.next_node
        print('None')
l_list=linked_list()
l_list.add('4')
l_list.add('40')
l_list.add('5')
l_list.print_list()
```

#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

In the add function we create a new node that will become our new root aka our new first element. Therefore we first assign the current root as the next_node of our new node. Afterwards we make our new node the new root.

Answer (score 0):

The `linked_list.root` attribute actually acts like a tail.  When a new node is added, it becomes the `next_node` of the original `root` and the `root` is assigned with that new node (making its content a tail, not a root).

Also, the Node class suggests a doubly linked list but its `previous_node` value is not properly assigned by linked_list.add.

If that is not your code, it is not a good example to learn from.  If it is, then it needs more work and you should probably draw on paper the links that should result from adding a node to the list.

For example:

```
linked_list.root
               |
               v
    None <-- node1 --> None
```

`linked_list.add(node2) ...`

What should happen:

```
linked_list.root
               |
               v
    None <-- node1 --+
               ^     |
               |     v 
               +--- node2 --> None
```

What actually happens:

```
    linked_list.root        # points to the last node added (i.e. tail)
                   |
                   v
        None <-- node2 --> None  # missing link to node1
                   ^       
                   |        
  None <-- node1 --+
```

Comment: No, it is not my code, it is a course on data structures on youtube, I didn't understand data structures well, can you recommend me some free resources to learn data structures perfectly?

Comment: Sorry, I can't recommend any good source. The internet wasn't even a dream when I learned these things.